# how to fetch the option selected by user while attempting the quiz made through servlets and jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to develop an online quiz through Servlets and Jsp.
I am using MYSQl as the backend database.
The requirement is  to display few random questions to user.
I have to store the results of the quiz in a separate table.
The table should have the details such as username, question presented to each user ,whether it was correct or incorrect

Currently I am able to display all the questions on a single web page  .

But I am unable to fetch the answers selected by the user while attempting the quiz.
I need to store each option selected by user and transfer it to a JSP page.

Below  is the code :-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Quiz";
        String username1="root";
        String password1="root";
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

            PreparedStatement st = null;
            ResultSet results = null;

            int limit=3;
            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username1,password1);
                String sql="SELECT  Questions.Question, Questions.option1, Questions.option2,Questions.option3, Questions.option4,Questions.correctanswer FROM Questions order by RAND() limit ?";
                st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setInt(1,limit);
                results = st.executeQuery();

                int i=1;

                    while (results.next())
                    {
                    String r1, r2, r3, r4, r5,r6;
                    r1 = results.getString(1);
                    r2 = results.getString(2);
                    r3 = results.getString(3);
                    r4 = results.getString(4);
                    r5 = results.getString(5);
                    r6 = results.getString(6);
                    out.println("<BODY BGCOLOR='powderblue'></BODY>" +
                            "<FORM method=\"post\" action= \"Results.jsp\" >" +
                            "<TABLE BORDER = 2 CELLPADDING = 4 CELLSPACING = 2>" +
                            "<TR><TD COLSPAN = 6 ALIGN = CENTER><H2><B>Quick Quiz</B></H2></TD></TR>");
                    out.println("<TR><TD>" + r1 + "</TD></TR>");
                    out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" id=\"input1\"  value = \"1\"  required> " + r2 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                    out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" id=\"input2\" value = \"2\">" + r3 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                    out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" id=\"input3\" value = \"3\">" + r4 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                    out.println("<TR><TD><input type = \"radio\" name = \"answer\" id=\"input4\" value = \"4\">" + r5 + "</TD></TR><BR>");
                    out.println("</TABLE>");

                    session.setAttribute("question"+i,r1);
                       session.setAttribute("correctanswer"+i, r6);

                  if (i <3)

                        {
                      out.println("</FORM></BODY></HTML>");
                        }

                     else
                        {
                         out.println("<BR><BR><INPUT type = \"submit\" value = \"Press to Submit\"></form></body></html>" );

                        }   
                 i++;

                    }

                   // session.setAttribute("selectedanswer1",(String)(request.getParameter("answer")) );  ---not working as expected          
                    results.close();
                   st.close();
                    con.close();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


            }
```

Request you to help me in fetching the result of the quiz.

I was also trying to display each questions in a separate web page and giving an option of "Next" button to move to the next question but I was unble to do that.
So I tried other way and gave all the questions on single page .But I am unable to fetch the option selected by user while attempting the quiz..

The required option which I have used is also not working properly.

Please help me in fetching the answer selected by user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your form isn't laid out properly.

Correct me if i misunderstand, but the generated html by your servlet should look something like this?

```html
    <BODY BGCOLOR='powderblue'></BODY>
    <FORM method="post" action= "Results.jsp" >
       <TABLE BORDER = 2 CELLPADDING = 4 CELLSPACING = 2>
          <TR>
             <TD COLSPAN = 6 ALIGN = CENTER>
                <H2><B>Quick Quiz</B></H2>
             </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD></TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input1"  value = "1"  required></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input2" value = "2"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input3" value = "3"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input4" value = "4"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
       </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    </BODY>
    <BODY BGCOLOR='powderblue'></BODY>
    <FORM method="post" action= "Results.jsp" >
       <TABLE BORDER = 2 CELLPADDING = 4 CELLSPACING = 2>
          <TR>
             <TD COLSPAN = 6 ALIGN = CENTER>
                <H2><B>Quick Quiz</B></H2>
             </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD></TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input1"  value = "1"  required></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input2" value = "2"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input3" value = "3"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input4" value = "4"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
       </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    </BODY>
    <BODY BGCOLOR='powderblue'></BODY>
    <FORM method="post" action= "Results.jsp" >
       <TABLE BORDER = 2 CELLPADDING = 4 CELLSPACING = 2>
          <TR>
             <TD COLSPAN = 6 ALIGN = CENTER>
                <H2><B>Quick Quiz</B></H2>
             </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD></TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input1"  value = "1"  required></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input2" value = "2"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input3" value = "3"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
          <TR>
             <TD><input type = "radio" name = "answer" id="input4" value = "4"></TD>
          </TR>
          <BR>
       </TABLE>
       <BR><BR><INPUT type = "submit" value = "Press to Submit">
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

Let's step through your html here..

You're creating the body more than once, for some reason, and self closing it.

You have multiple forms, and even have multiple separate HTML elements, when in any valid HTML document, there should only be one.

A typical form should look something like this

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <form method='post' action='Results.jsp'>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>What's the capitol of the United States?</legend>
   <input type="radio" name="question1_answer" value="1" id="question1_answer1">
   <label for="question1_answer1">Pennsylvania</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question1_answer" value="2" id="question1_answer2">
   <label for="question1_answer2">New York</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question1_answer" value="3" id="question1_answer3">
   <label for="question1_answer3">Washington D.C.</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question1_answer4" value="4" id="question1_answer4">
   <label for="question1_answer4">Texas</label>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>What's 10 divided by 2</legend>
   <input type="radio" name="question2_answer" value="1" id="question2_answer1">
   <label for="question2_answer1">5</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question2_answer" value="2" id="question2_answer2">
   <label for="question2_answer2">3</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question2_answer" value="3" id="question2_answer3">
   <label for="question2_answer3">12</label>
  
   <input type="radio" name="question2_answer4" value="4" id="question2_answer4">
   <label for="question2_answer4">8</label>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Press to Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your servlet, you'd do something like this to get the answers.

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    String answer = request.getAttribute("question"+i+"_answer");
}
```

Edit: Servlet Code could look like this, roughly.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Quiz";
String username1="root";
String password1="root";
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

PreparedStatement st = null;
ResultSet results = null;

int limit=3;
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username1,password1);
    String sql="SELECT  Questions.Question, Questions.option1, Questions.option2,Questions.option3, Questions.option4,Questions.correctanswer FROM Questions order by RAND() limit ?";
    st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    st.setInt(1,limit);
    results = st.executeQuery();

    int questionnumber = 0;

    out.println("<html><body><form method='post' action='Results.jsp'>");
    while (results.next())
    {
        questionnumber++;
        String question = results.getString(1);
        HashMap<Integer, String> questions = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        questions.put(1, results.getString(2));
        questions.put(2, results.getString(3));
        questions.put(3, results.getString(4));
        questions.put(4, results.getString(5));

        foreach(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : questions.entrySet()){
            String answertext = entry.getValue();
            Integer answernumber = entry.getKey();
            out.println("<input type='radio' name='question" + questionnumber + "_answer' value='" + answernumber + "' id='question" + questionnumber + "_answer" + answernumber + "'>");
            out.println("<label for='question" + questionnumber + "_answer" + answernumber + "'>" + answertext + "</label>")
        }

        out.println("<fieldset><legend>" + question + "</legend>");

        out.println("</fieldset>");
    }
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='Press to Submit'></form></body></html>");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just do an loop, output the questions text, the question number and then answer numbers & text using above as a template?

Comment: Thankyou @zack6849 for helping. Yes, you are right. But I have to fetch few questions from database and display them one after another that is why I used above method.But my form is not displayed properly as you figured it out.                                                                                                 I used a loop for display questions but the way which I did is not correct , will you let me know  how to correct my code.

Comment: Why not just use a for loop and use the template I provided?

Comment: if you see my code I have used a loop..you are not able to understand my question

Comment: I have tried many ways still it was not working that is why I asked the question.

Comment: added to answer.